# How to build and deploy pgadmin to OpenShift?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift

I want to deploy pgadmin in my OpenShift namespace, but when I am deploying the default pgadmin image from docker.hub, I have an error:

```
    /entrypoint.sh: line 8: can't create /pgadmin4/config_distro.py: Permission denied
    You need to define the PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL and PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD environment variables.
```

But, I can't access full priveleges OpenShift, i am not admin cluster, i can't do oc adm policy add-scc.
I tried to create Dockerfile

```
FROM dpage/pgadmin4 as pgadmin4
USER root 
RUN chown 1000640000:1000640000 /pgadmin4 && \
    sed -i 's/5050/1000720000/g' /etc/passwd && \
    sed -i 's/5050/1000720000/g' /etc/group && \
    find / -user 5050 -exec chown 1000720000 {} \; && \
    find / -group 5050 -exec chown :1000720000 {} \; && \
    sed 's@python /run_pgadmin.py@python /pgadmin4/run_pgadmin.py@g' /entrypoint.sh

USER 1000640000

VOLUME /var/lib/pgadmin
EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And if i docker build and deploy to OpenShift, I will still have an error

Maybe there is some other way to bypass the ban and install pgadmin?

Comment: try to change `chown 1000640000:1000640000 /pgadmin4` with `chown -R 1000640000:1000640000 /pgadmin4`. And add envs to dockerfile: `ENV PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=some_mail@mail.com`, `ENV PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=some_password`

Comment: Hm, maybe I wrote it wrong, i have error in log
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/lib/pgadmin and Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what @rzlvmp advised you. Also do not `EXPOSE 80 443`. In Openshift if you do not have a `cluster-admin` role to perform `oc adm policy add-scc` which even if you have it, it is not the good idea to dealing with scc anyhow, you are not able to expose port lower than 1024. Use `EXPOSE 8080 8443` for example. Only process started under `root` UID could use port lower then 1024.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions work better in OpenShift if you recognize your container runs with GROUPID=0 instead of trying to fine tune for the uid.

Instead of embedding that high uid in your container image, chgrp 0, and chmod g+rwx